# ANDROID, Sharing a big non English (Arabic) text via Whatsapp shares incomplete text

Tags: android, sharing, whatsapp

Do you have any idea why sharing an Arabic text -which length is greater than 2000 chars- goes very smoothly via all apps except Whatsapp?
my code works fine for all apps, but for Whatsapp results an incomplete text shared :(

my code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    String textToShare = "";
    textToShare = verseTxtV.getText()+".\n";
    textToShare += chapterName+"\n\n";
    textToShare += "تفسير ابن كثير"+": \n";
    textToShare += tafseerTxt.length() > 5 ? tafseerTxt+"\n\n" : "";    
    textToShare += "via @[Learn Ayah]"+"\n"+ "Pray for us.";    
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
    return shareIntent;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will be able to get much help without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, i submitted my code,
the code works fine for all apps eligible for text sharing except Whatsapp which shares only around 2300 chars of the text.

Comment: OK, that looks fine. Your question implies that this problem is limited to Arabic. Have you tried longer prose in other languages (e.g., English)? If it cuts off at ~2300 or ~4600 characters, it is likely to be a language-independent limit. Regardless, this does not appear to be an issue with your code so much as it is with Whatsapp, and you would have to ask Whatsapp why they have the limit.

Comment: Thank you, it is apparently Whatsapp related limitation, i just tried sharing an English and another Arabic blogs from chrome,
the English text sharing was also limited for around 4170 chars.
i might modify my code to loop and share the text until it is fully shared, however it is not a decent solution.